# Only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following SQL statement. It's throws the following error: "Only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression". The goal of my sql statement is to get the name of the employee who made the 'cheapest' bribe.

The part between the brackets return the employee_id and the money it costs a day (of the relative cheapest bribe). These are two results while I only want the employee_id. So I just want to use the MIN part to get the right employee_id. How can I do this?

```
SELECT Voornaam, Achternaam
FROM Medewerker m JOIN
     (
      SELECT Medewerker_id
      FROM Steekpenning
      ORDER BY -1*Bedrag/(julianday(Begindatum) - julianday(Einddatum))
      limit 1
     ) s
     on m.Medewerker_id = s.Medewerker_id;
```

EDITED the answer. How can I expand this query to only show the bribes started this month? I think I need to use something like this? (julianday(Begindatum) - julianday('now')) > 31 but where?

Regards.
Cas

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the following will work in SQLite:

```
select Firstname, Surname 
from Employee e join
     (select employee_id
      from bribe
      order by -1*Amount/(julianday(Startdate) - julianday(Enddate))
      limit 1
     ) b
     on e.employee_id = b.employee_id;
```

Comment: Word of advice.  If Gordon Linoff even THINKS it is right, well, it is.

Comment: Hehe okay xD I have one more question. Where should I add the line if I only want the bribes that were started less than 31 days ago?

Comment: @user3013897 . . . You would add that in the subquery, right after the `from` clause.